# scope change in a directive not a apply in view

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

I have a directive in a template.html, included by a ng-include, in this directive I change the scope , but it is not change in my view

Here is my html

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="modal">
        <div ng-show="showDIv">Somthing to controll</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-include src="template.html">
</div>
```

Here is my template

```
 <a ng-support></a>
```

And here is my directive

```
app.directive('ngSupport', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
           elem.bind('click', function(e) {
               $("#modal").dialog({height:518,width:900,modal:true });
               scope.showDiv = true;
               scope.$apply();

            });
        }
    };
});
```

When i change the scope in the directive it is not apply in the view, anyone could help please ?

Comment: Is `showDIv` vs. `showDiv` (notice casing) a typo here or in your code?

Answer (score 1):

`ng-include` creates a new scope so `scope.showDiv` only affects the local scope.
Depending on how you want to structure your application, you could try accessing `scope.$parent.showDiv` instead, but it is not really future proof as it will depend on the HTML nesting.

A better solution would be to have the `showDiv` property stored inside an object in the parent scope. For example `scope.ui = {}`, this way, when you set `scope.ui.showDiv = true` in your directive, it will look up the parent scope automatically (using prototype inheritance), instead of adding the property to the local scope.

Finally, another solution would be to refactor your code to make it less complex: I think using a ng-include just for adding one element is an overkill, you could put directly `<a ng-support></a>` inside your html, which would avoid the problem you have with an intermediary scope being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to broadcast an event, and watch for it in the controller. Something like this.

```
app.directive('ngSupport', function($rootScope){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
           elem.bind('click', function(e) {
               $("#modal").dialog({height:518,width:900,modal:true });
               $rootScope.$broadcast('event:modal-clicked');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

With this in your controller.

```
$scope.$on('event:modal-clicked', function() {
    $scope.showDiv = true;
});
```